# How can I bind multiple SQL queries to a single asp repeater

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, data-binding, repeater

So I have a query that looks like this:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * From Table1 WHERE conditions";
DataTable tempTable = helper.ExecuteQuery(cmd);
tempTable.TableName = "MainRecords";
ds.Tables.Add(tempTable);
```

where ds is a DataSet (global variable) and then in another function I bind my information to an asp:Repeater named MainRecords like this:

```
MainRecords.DataSource = ds.Tables["MainRecords"];
MainRecords.DataBind();
```

My question is how can I bind a second query (like the one above but with different results) to the same repeater so I can display them simultaneously,  something like this:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="MainRecords" runat="server">
<ItemTemplate>
    <tr>
        <td><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "InfoFromTable1")%></td>
        <td><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "InfoFromTable2")%></td>
    </tr>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

I found some things here but nothing seemed to help me.

Comment: How are is the queries related?

Comment: You must make this "join"/"Union" on sql selection...

Comment: Well that is my real problem, I can't join the queries because if I take them separately they return correct data but if I try and join them I get some ugly looking numbers which weren't suppose to be that big (I asked someone I work with who is better than me at Databases and he suggested I should take them separately)

Comment: Your results have to match and have some sort of link otherwise you might get 11 results from the first query and only 9 from the second.  You can always use `RowDataBound` event or `ToString()` to tidy up the data for display but you really are going to need to do some sort of `Join` on your database tables

Comment: I don't really know how to explain this. In my case I have something like a store in which you have 2 types of sales (normal products sales and focus products sales). I can guarantee that my selects will return the same number of rows but if I try and join them something happens (I cant figure out what) and it will make sums (for respective sales) wrong ... and that's why I'm willing to take them separately. I hope it is all clear now.